# Decrypting a ciphertext in ElGamal's cryptosystem

Tags: elgamal-encryption

I am a student in computer science currently working on a problem set in cryptography (practical problem but stuck on the math part).

Basically, suppose we receive a message that has been encrypted using ElGamal's crypto system and our goal is to decrypt and completely recover the message.

The initial plaintext is a sequence $p_1p_2\ldots p_m$. We are given a hashed version of the public key SHA256$(g^s)$ (so $s$ is the private key and $g^s$ the public one). For the encryption, it is said that an $r_1$ value is sampled uniformly at random and then for some given value $u\in\mathbb{Z}_q$, $r_i=u^{i-1}r_1$ for all the remaining $i$'s. The cipher text is then $c_i=(g^{r_i},p_ig^{r_is})_{i\in[m]}$.

Overall, we are given $p$, $q$, $g$, $u$, the hashed public key $H$ and the cipher text $c_i$ as a tuple.

The problem I have is that I don't really see what computations we have to do in order to recover the entire original sequence. One of the assistants told me to find some $p_i$'s and then use them to decrypt the cipher but I don't see where that brings me.
The $r$'s are unknown and even if we know $g^{r_i}$, as we are given rather huge values, we can't compute the log.

I am a little lost here to be honest (I don't have an enormous background in algebra) so if someone has some advice on what I should do, I would truly appreciate it.

Thanks :)

Comment: But isn't the private key $s$? Can't you raise $g^{r_i}$ to the $s$ like in the regular scheme?

Comment: @yacovm yes $s$ is the private key, but we don't know it so we can't do some computation with it. I guess the best solution would somehow be to find a way to know $r_1$ but I don't know how.

Comment: Could you first read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption then tell us where did you fail?

Comment: So you're trying to decrypt without knowing the private key? Is that the assignment?

Comment: I guess I'm starting to think that we are missing some crucial elements in the problem statement (even though that's not the case). Indeed @yacovm we do not have access to the private key $s$. We only have access to a hash of $g^s$. The TA told us to guess some $p_i$'s but I don't really see how to do this.

Comment: @kelalaka I guess that in our scenario we have to proceed a little differently than how the real decryption process works, that's partially why I am confused :p

Comment: What's the size of $p$, in bits or decimal digits? If that's small enough, there can be attacks. Also, is $(p-1)/2$ prime, or a composite with non-trivial factors?

Comment: @fgrieu $p$ is a power of two, to be precise it is $2^{1024}$ so 309 digits. If I'm not mistaken, $(p-1)/2$ is not prime. I think that I'm close to something but computations with modulos is always quite challenging.

Comment: If $p$ is a large power of two, it's not prime, and $(p-1)/2$ can't be prime. Are you sure of this?

Comment: Ignoring what you said about $p$: I think the crux of the problem is that the $r_i$ are not random, as they should. Just to check that we got the equations right: you should be able to verify that $g^{r_i}=(g^{r_1})^{(u^{i-1})}\bmod p$ (notice that the $g^{r_i}$ are the first part of the ciphertexts). Now do something similar with the second part of the ciphertexts and you should be able to get all the $p_i/p_1\bmod p$. And then..

Comment: @fgrieu I’m sure that p is not prime (that’s trivial) and pretty sure that (p-1)/2 is. I will be looking into what you say. But to clarify: $r_1$ is random, $u$ also is (uniformly random in $\mathbb{Z}_q$ and all the remaining $r_i$’s are generated based on $r_1$ and the preceding $u$. So the trick I believe is to somehow find some $r_i$ and go further from there.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find $r_{1}$. For this, try to see if there is a relation between $c_{i}$ and $c_{j}$, mostly between $g^{r_{i}}$ and $g^{r_{j}}$. Maybe you can find a $c$ such that $g^{c}=g^{r_{i}}/g^{r_{j}}$.
Then you can compute $g^{s}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) yes that was my main goal, in fact, finding a single $r_i$ is sufficient here because from there we can easily find $r_1$ and everything else. But, computations with modulos are quite tricky so I’m doing my best to work on this and find a solution.